Monitor fluentd.conf with exec plugin
I have fluentd deployed in K8s container. The below is fluentd configuration to monitor the fluentd.conf. If there is any change done to fluentd.conf file the reload.sh script will run which will trigger SIGHUP signal.
<source>
  @type exec
  tag fluent
  command sh /opt/scripts/reload/reload.sh
  run_interval 40s
  keys none
</source>


I have deployed this as a ConfigMap and mounting in /etc/fluent/ location.
Below is reload script reload.sh.
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$(find /etc/fluent/* -type l -newerct '50 seconds ago' -name "*.conf")" ]; then
    echo "Files have been modified"
    kill -12 $(pgrep -f 'fluentd')
else
    echo "No files have been modified"
fi

The issue I'm facing is when I deploy fluentd first time this config also gets triggered and fluentd will reload which is unnecessory. So is there any way to avoid this?
Fluentd version: 1.16.2
